# GLX Context Creation Error: GLXBadFBConfig

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, glx

I used `glXCreateContext` to create the contexts, but the function is deprecated and always results in an OpenGL Version 3.0, where I would need at least 4. Now, if I have understood it right, `GLXContext glXCreateContextAttribsARB(Display* dpy, GLXFBConfig config, GLXContext share_context, Bool direct, const int* attrib_list);` replaced `glXCreateContext`. The "new" function allows for explicitly specifying the major version, minor version, profile et cetera in it's `attrib_list` like this for example:

```
int context_attribs[] =
{
    GLX_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 4,
    GLX_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 5,
    GLX_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB,         GLX_CONTEXT_DEBUG_BIT_ARB,
    GLX_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB,  GLX_CONTEXT_COMPABILITY_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
    None
};
```

Then use the function:

```
glXCreateContextAttribsARB(dpy, config, NULL, true, context_attribs);
```

That is how I have done it in my program. The window is already created and dpy is a valid pointer to Display. `config` I have defined like this:

```
// GLXFBConfig config; created at the beginning of the program
int attrib_list[] =
{
    GLX_RENDER_TYPE,    GLX_RGBA_BIT,
    GLX_RED_SIZE,       8,
    GLX_GREEN_SIZE,     8,
    GLX_BLUE_SIZE,      8,
    GLX_DEPTH_SIZE,     24,
    GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER,   True,
    None
};
int nAttribs;

config = glXChooseFBConfig(dpy, 0, attrib_list, &nAttribs);
```

Checking with `glxinfo`, I have the correct visual for it; `vi` has been set to `0x120`, which I can confirm with `glxinfo | grep 0x120`. It exactly fulfills the above.
So far, so good. But when running the application (compiling works fine), I get the following error:

```
X Error of failed request: GLXBadFBConfig
Major opcode of failed request: 152 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request: 34 ()
Serial number of failed request: 31
Current serial number in output stream: 31
```

Now, this is what the error is about:

> If <config> does not support compatible OpenGL contexts providing the requested API major and minor version, forward-compatible flag, and debug context flag, GLXBadFBConfig is generated.

So, the problem is pretty straightforward. I don't know how to solve it though. What it essentially means is that no OpenGL context corresponding both to the attributes I specified in `attrib_list[]` and the attributes in `context_attribs` can be found. With `glxinfo | grep Max` I confirmed that my highest possible OpenGL Version is 4.5. I would like to hear your advice on what I should do now. I have played around with the attributes in `context_attribs` for a while, but did not get anywhere. Maybe the problem really is in another place. Maybe my conception of the GLX functions is flawed in general, please point it out if so!

Comment: "I confirmed that my highest possible OpenGL Version is 4.5"  Make sure that's for Compatibility contexts like you're requesting, and not only for Core contexts.  Up until fairly recently Mesa only supported GL versions greater than 3.0 on Core contexts.  Also, edit in a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The specification of [GLX_ARB_create_context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context#Context_types) is clear about when `GLXBadFBConfig` error may be returned:

> ```
>   * If <config> does not support compatible OpenGL contexts
>     providing the requested API major and minor version,
>     forward-compatible flag, and debug context flag, GLXBadFBConfig
>     is generated.
> ```

This maybe confusing (as error has nothing to do with already created `GLXFBConfig`), but I that's what we have. So the most obvious reason for the error you have is that your system **doesn't actually support** `OpenGL 4.5 Compatible Profile` you have requested - it might have, though, support `OpenGL 4.5 Core Profile` or compatible/core profiles of lower versions. This is a pretty *common case for Mesa drivers* supporting only OpenGL 3.3+ Core Profiles and just OpenGL 3.0 Compatible Profile for many GPUs (but not all - some gets better Compatible Profile support like Radeons).

If you are not familiar yet with **conception of OpenGL profiles** - you can [start here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context#Context_types).

`glxinfo` shows information about both Core and Compatible profiles, which could be filtered out like this:

```
glxinfo | grep -e "OpenGL version" -e "Core" -e "Compatible"
```

which returns this on a virtual Ubuntu 18.04 to me:

```
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.2.8
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 19.2.8
```

If your application really needs OpenGL 4.5 or higher, than just try creating a context with `GLX_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB` bit instead of `GLX_CONTEXT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE_BIT_ARB` and ensure not using any deprecated functionality.

Note that requesting a *Compatible Profile* of specific version usually makes no sense - it is enough just skipping version parameters to get the highest supported one and filter out unsupported versions from `GL_VERSION`/`GL_MAJOR_VERSION` of already created context like it was done in days before profiles have been introduced. In case of a *Core Profile*, it might be tricky on some OpenGL drivers requesting the highest supported version (e.g. without disabled functionality of versions higher than requested) - the following code snippet could be useful:

```cpp
  //! A dummy XError handler which just skips errors
  static int xErrorDummyHandler (Display* , XErrorEvent* ) { return 0; }
  ...

  Window      aWindow    = ...;
  Display*    aDisp      = ...;
  GLXFBConfig anFBConfig = ...;
  bool toDebugContext = false;

  GLXContext  aGContext  = NULL
  const char* aGlxExts   = glXQueryExtensionsString (aDisp, aVisInfo.screen);
  if (!checkGlExtension (aGlxExts, "GLX_ARB_create_context_profile"))
  {
    std::cerr << "GLX_ARB_create_context_profile is NOT supported\n";
    return;
  }

  // Replace default XError handler to ignore errors.
  // Warning - this is global for all threads!
  typedef int (*xerrorhandler_t)(Display* , XErrorEvent* );
  xerrorhandler_t anOldHandler = XSetErrorHandler(xErrorDummyHandler);

  typedef GLXContext (*glXCreateContextAttribsARB_t)(Display* dpy, GLXFBConfig config,
                                                     GLXContext share_context, Bool direct,
                                                     const int* attrib_list);
  glXCreateContextAttribsARB_t aCreateCtxProc = (glXCreateContextAttribsARB_t )glXGetProcAddress((const GLubyte* )"glXCreateContextAttribsARB");
  int aCoreCtxAttribs[] =
  {
    GLX_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
    GLX_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 2,
    GLX_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB,  GLX_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
    GLX_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB,         toDebugContext ? GLX_CONTEXT_DEBUG_BIT_ARB : 0,
    0, 0
  };

  // try to create a Core Profile of highest OpenGL version (up to 4.6)
  for (int aLowVer4 = 6; aLowVer4 >= 0 && aGContext == NULL; --aLowVer4)
  {
    aCoreCtxAttribs[1] = 4;
    aCoreCtxAttribs[3] = aLowVer4;
    aGContext = aCreateCtxProc (aDisp, anFBConfig, NULL, True, aCoreCtxAttribs);
  }
  for (int aLowVer3 = 3; aLowVer3 >= 2 && aGContext == NULL; --aLowVer3)
  {
    aCoreCtxAttribs[1] = 3;
    aCoreCtxAttribs[3] = aLowVer3;
    aGContext = aCreateCtxProc (aDisp, anFBConfig, NULL, True, aCoreCtxAttribs);
  }
  bool isCoreProfile = aGContext != NULL;
  if (!isCoreProfile)
  {
    std::cerr << "glXCreateContextAttribsARB() failed to create Core Profile\n";
  }

  // try to create Compatible Profile
  if (aGContext == NULL)
  {
    int aCtxAttribs[] =
    {
      GLX_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB, toDebugContext ? GLX_CONTEXT_DEBUG_BIT_ARB : 0,
      0, 0
    };
    aGContext = aCreateCtxProc (aDisp, anFBConfig, NULL, True, aCtxAttribs);
  }
  XSetErrorHandler (anOldHandler);

  // fallback to glXCreateContext() as last resort
  if (aGContext == NULL)
  {
    aGContext = glXCreateContext (aDisp, aVis.get(), NULL, GL_TRUE);
    if (aGContext == NULL) { std::cerr << "glXCreateContext() failed\n"; }
  }
```